# Include Vimeo's Froogaloop library

Tags: javascript

I have a custom module that has a JavaScript file in it. The JavaScript file is calling on the Vimeo API, which has a custom library created for it (similar to jQuery).

How can I use this library in the custom module's .js file? I've tried putting Froogaloop (the Vimeo library) inside of sites/all/libraries and then using its syntax it in the .js file within the custom module, but it's not picking the library up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your js file even working?

Is your JavaScript file jQuery?

**In Drupal, you wrap your jQuery code like this**

```
(function ($) {

    //code goes here

})(jQuery);
```

For Example:

```
(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".button").click(function () {
             $(this).next('.content').hide();
         });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

**Not sure if you did this already.**

Did you also add the frugaloop js to your module? Putting it on the libraries folder doesn't do anything unless you call it.

Use the function [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) to call it.

Comment: Correct, I do have it wrapped and jQuery is functioning correctly. However, I have not called the library in the custom module. I'll give that an attempt. Thank you.

Comment: When in doubt, just look at how other modules are calling their js files.

Comment: Words of wisdom - Froogaloop now works. Thank you!!